# How to Manage Content Types

Tags: nodes

[image]

I am trying to add custom fields for a Quiz Component (Multiple Choice Question). However, when I go to Home>Admin>Structure>Content types, the only types that appear are Article, Basic page and Quiz (non of the components). I can add my own content type but cannot seem to get the already existing content types to appear in this menu.

In short, how do I control what content appears on this menu.

Thanks for your help and sorry for the noob question. Just getting started out.

Comment: Which node types are missing from the list exactly? That page works by loading all know node types and simply listing them in a table. If it's excluding certain types, there must be code in there doing that deliberately, either in s custom or contributed (not core) module. Is it possible you're mistaking these other "components" for content types when they're in fact something different?

Comment: Probably you have missed clicking "Save" button after adding all the fields.. :)

Comment: @parth.k That would not explain why the content type is missing, since you first create a content type and then add the fields.

Answer (score 1):

The admin/structure/types page lists all the content types implemented by modules, or the content type you created.
In the case of the Quiz module, there are content types created from sub-modules, such as the *Short Answer* module, all listed under the *Quiz Question* package. Once you enable the modules you need, you will see extra content types, on admin/structure/types.

Comment: All of the sub-modules that I am using (multichoice/ truefalse) are enabled under the module menu (checkbox to the left the sub-module content type clicked). Still only seeing the three types in pic above.

Comment: Whats more, I can access the appropriate contact management page by appending the question type to the end of the URL (i.e., http://localhost:8888/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fstructure%252Ftypes%252Fmanage%252Ftruefalse), so I know that it is enabled. Just can't itto appear on admin/structure/types

Answer (score 0):

### Try 1

It may be an outdated cache. They should be cleared automatically when you install a module but it is possible it didn't get flushed completely. Perform a full cache flush using drush. Or visit /admin/config/development/performance

This may cause those items to magically appear.

### Try 2

I did this in Drupal 6 I think. Not 7.

I have run into something similar. I created several content types and for some reason one of them was not in this menu. I never figured out why but I was able to fix this by simply editing the management menu directly.

While you're in there check if the menu item is unchecked or in an unusual location. If you still can't find it you can create a new link in the appropriate area.

### Try 3

Check the documentation. As @Clive mentioned in the comments these may be other entity types.

### Try 4

If you don't have too much built roll-back to your db from before the quiz module was installed and install again. Or if you don't have a rollback point, uninstall the module and install again. Not a fun process but it may tweak something in the database.

Comment: Thanks for these thoughtful answers. However, nothing is working. Even with uninstall and reinstall, I cannot find a way to get to ....admin/structure/types/manage/truefalse without keying it into the URL. Maybe its an issue with the program. I'll just edit manually for now.